# The 2% of the parts produced by a machine are defective. If a random sample of 60 parts is taken, what is the probability that....

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

The 2% of the parts produced by a machine are defective. If a random sample of 60 parts is taken, what is the probability that there are between 0 and 2 defective parts?

Hi! I need help with this exercise. I know i have to check first if the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$ is approximately normal. For that I need that $np \geq 10$ and $n(1-p) \geq 10$.

So, when checking that the first one fail.

$60(0.02) = 1.2 < 10$

So that's mean is not approximately normal? If that is so, what do I do then?

I did this $\sigma_{\hat{p}}=\sqrt{\frac{0.02(1-0.02)}{60}}=0.018074$

Then,

$\hat{p_1}=\frac{0}{60}=0$

$\hat{p_2}=\frac{2}{60}=0.033$

$z_{1}=\frac{0-0.02}{0.018074}=-1.11$

$z_{2}=\frac{0.033-0.02}{0.018074}=0.72$

So the probability,

$P(0<\hat{p}<0.033)=P(-1.11<z<0.72)=P(z<0.72)-P(z<-1.11)=0.7640-0.1342=0.6298$

This is what I have but I'm not sure since $np< 10$

Comment: Without approximating binomial distribution as normal distribution, what is the probability that there are $0$ defective parts among the $60$ parts? $1$ defective part? $2$ defective parts?

Comment: So I shall I use just the binomial distribution to calculate it when the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$ is not normal approximated?

Comment: Also because there are only $3$ cases ($0,1,2$) to sum.